# What is the meaning of the check box and circle in this iTune U

Tags: itunes

[image]

If it means watched, then I saw the check box is over there even though I selected unwatched column.

Does it mean downloaded? There is no tool tips and it's kind of silly to have 2 columns expressing the same thing.

The checkbox may means downloaded. What about the circle to the left of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox is a tool for downloaded items to specify if you want that specific item to sync to your device. There is a setting in your iTunes device list to sync only checked items in iTunes:
[image]

If you have that setting turned on, unchecking any song or video will tell iTunes not to sync that item to your device during the next sync.

The circle is a progress indicator for downloaded items:

- A **filled circle** indicates that the item is **unplayed**.
- A **half circle** indicates that the item is **partially played**.
- **No circle** indicates that the item has been **played to completion**.

Answer (score 0):

The blue circle tells you how much of the media file your have played. A full circle means that it has never been played or has been marked as unplayed. A half circle means it has been partially played. No circle means it has been fully played.

As for the checkboxes, they are just for marking purposes and can have multiple functions. You can create a new playlist with the marked files, sync them to an iDevice, tell iTunes only to play marked files, etc.

Of course, a file you have not downloaded will not have a checkbox, as it does not exist on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Check box is for you to check when you have completed a lesson.  The circles gradually fill  up as you complete the lesson.